# How to access a URL with port with out disabling firewall

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, port, web-deployment

I have a server to which I connect using VPN. I have a deployed a site on this on IIS server. URL for the site is  "http://localhost:8080/mysite". when  I use this Url on server it is opening up.

But When I use it`s ip address Let`s say http://172.x.x.x:8080/mysite it is not accessible. (not on the server not from my dev machine (Which uses VPN)).

But if I disable firewall on server then It is accessible using the IP and port 8080 also or if I change the port number of deployed site to 80 then also I can access it(without disabling firewall).

Is there any way so that I can use my port number 8080 and also don`t need to disable firewall on server.

Comment: 8080 port is working status stop your 8080 port?

Comment: Poke a 8080-sized hole in the firewall.